# Sharing a single common boundary line within two polygons with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, leaflet-draw, topojson, leaflet-geoman

Is it possible in Leaflet, to share a single common boundary within two polygons, other than two overlapped boundaries within a MultiPolygon layer?

In this plugin ([leaflet-geoman](https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman)), they have mentioned there is an option in pro version, called [pining](https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman#pinning-). But in that pining option (you can see it on the gif), it has duplicate boundaries on top of each other. What I want to achieve is, multipolygons must share common boundaries like on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57543715/deduplicate-polygon-state-country-shared-boundaries) question. But on this quetion it was about MultiLineStrings, not about MultiPolygons. The answer was given using TopoJSON. It has a [method](https://github.com/topojson/topojson-client/blob/master/README.md#mesh) called `topojson.mesh` which

> Returns the GeoJSON MultiLineString geometry object representing the mesh for the specified object in the given topology. This is useful for rendering strokes in complicated objects efficiently, as edges that are shared by multiple features are only stroked once.

But there is no method for returning MultiPolygons for a given topology. It only has a [method](https://github.com/topojson/topojson-client/blob/master/README.md#merge) for returning MultiPolygons called `topojson.merge` wich

> to merge multiple polygons into a single polygon whilst removing interior borders.

So my ultimate goal is to have MultiPolygon layer which consist with single shared boundary within two polygons, not duplicated boundaries on top of each other or overlapped boundaries. What I need is exactly in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rWVRIoIG3gc). But it is done using overlapped boundaries. Not using shared single boundaries.

I tried it using the exact [plugin](https://github.com/UW-Macrostrat/Leaflet.draw.topology) used on above video. It has [mentioned](https://github.com/UW-Macrostrat/Leaflet.draw.topology/issues/2) on repository that

> In its current design, editing large datasets is not possible because of the massive amount of time required to find matching and missing vertices.

Is there anyway I can achieve this using Leaflet or any other method.

Comment: You probably want to do some research on TopoJSON.

Comment: `@IvanSanchez` Have you came across any need like above, Any possible hint on where should I look for on TopoJSON would be highly appreciated. Thank you for your directions.

Comment: Just have a look at TopoJSON depcification at https://github.com/topojson/topojson-specification and how polygons/multipolygons are constructed from basic elements called `arc`s. Each `arc` as an array of coordinates which you refer to by it's index in the array of all arcs. So common polygon boundary can be specified only once as one `arc` element and then referenced as many times as needed when onstructing polygons/multipolygons.

Comment: `@TomazicM` Thanks so much. It gave me some idea. I'll look in to more details.

Comment: You have a nice example of the concept in the online TopoJSON editor https://geo.land/. If you look at the default world map, you'll se that borders between countries appear as `arc` property only once. Then, when used as actual polygons describing border between two bordering countries, common border `arc` index appears in one country unsigned and in the other country with negative index, since polygon orientation goes the other way.

Comment: `@TomazicM` I checked the link you referenced and I still cannot understand how to verify or check "you'll se that borders between countries appear as `arc` property only once"

Comment: GIS SE site policy requires focused questions. Now that you broadened your question to any mapping library, you risk it being closed as to broad. I would recommend you revert back to your original question.

Comment: `@TomazicM` Thanks so much for pointing it out! I reverted it back :)

Comment: `@TomazicM` Can I **comment** an answer I found using another library? Will it be a violation of any GIS SE site policy?